# Turning the specific into the generic?

Tags: discussion

The question [Do I need Transit visa for Germany, travelling from India to Poland via Germany with Polish D-Type National Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40388/do-i-need-transit-visa-for-germany-travelling-from-india-to-poland-via-germany) was asked and answered. The OP indicated in a comment to the single answer (at the time of this question) that it answered his question, although he has not yet marked it as accepted.

I was thinking of editing the question (and title), removing all specifics and making it extremely generic, but that would be a fairly large edit, and so am seeking opinions/approval/consensus here first.

My proposed edit would be somthing like:

**Title: If I hold a Schengen-area Country's National D-Type (Long Stay) Visa, do I need a transit visa to travel through a second S-Area country?**

The body of the message could be similarly edited. I was thinking this might be helpful in order to avoid duplicate questions of a similar nature. (My wording above is quick and dirty, and could/should be even further refined.)

Comment: Yup I agree, I think you can just create a new question and answer more broadly. @Relaxed [did that for Schengen transit visa](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area), and it became the reference for duplicate questions on the topic.

Comment: Actually, reading Relaxed's Q&A, I believe it answers the question I'm referring to as well, so no need to do it. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Of late (by that, I mean the past few months), the site has been getting a LOT of questions related to Schengen visas with very similar answers. Even though the countries in question might be different, the answers are usually the same for Schengen area countries and tourist visas.

I know that it's usually frowned upon but I believe this case deserves to be standardised using a community wiki answer on Schengen visas with country specifics stripped out.

Comment: Apologies for not inserting links to back up. Posting from mobile.